# Can't download or build allegro

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, cmake

Please help me.

I am trying to install allegro to my debian jessie 8.5 system.

Okay so first I added the PPA of allegro

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:allegro/5.2
```

Then I did `sudo apt-get update` which says:

> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/allegro/5.2/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Naturally `sudo apt-get install liballegro5-dev` doesn't locate the package.

So I thought I'd just fix it some other day and decided to build from source. Thus I downloaded the source for allegro (`allegro-5.2.1.1`).

After extracting it, making a build folder, running `cmake ..` from build folder I got the error message:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:621 (message):
>
> X11 support requires Xcursor library.

Then I did a `sudo apt-get install libxcursor-dev` but apt-get cant locate that package. `apt-cache search xcursor` says there is a libxcursor1 package but it seems to be already installed in my system.

I've tried 'rm -rf'ing the build folder and trying to cmake again, but it doesn't work.

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libxcursor-dev says there is a libxcursor-dev but my apt-get can't get it. Also, the PPAs arent being updated. Is it because of my sources.list? It has the following lines:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib
```

Now I'm all out of ideas guys, please offer whatever suggestions/links/solutions you have.

Comment: did you install all these dependencies? `apt-get install build-essential git cmake cmake-curses-gui xorg-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu-dev`

Comment: Everything is installed to the newest version except apt-get cmake-curses-gui and xorg-dev, both of which apt-get says it cant locate. @Dylan

Comment: is `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian lenny main` in the sources list aka `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Ahhh @DylanRz you are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found what was wrong. The sources.list were misconfigured. When I added

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

to the `sources.list` file (inspired by @DylanRz), all problems resolved themselves.

I must have messed something up long ago when I was selecting mirrors.